# Property 'clientId' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular

In my component i have declared

```
export class UserPatientsReportFormComponent implements OnInit {
clientId: number ;
```

this is my oninit function

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      
      this.clientId = params.id == undefined ? null : this.commonService.encryptValue(params.id, false);
      
    });
```

and this is where i tried to use this clientId and face the issue.Below in patientId i tried to use this.clientId.Here i face the issue. how should i fixed it

```
patientReportForm=this.getGroup({patientId : this.clientId ,hubxCategoryId:"",notes:""})
getGroup(data:any=null)
{
  data=data || {patientId : 0,hubxCategoryId :"",notes:""}
  return new FormGroup({
    patientId:new FormControl(data.patientId),
    hubxCategoryId :new FormControl(data.hubxCategoryId),
    notes:new FormControl(data.notes)
  })
}
```

this.clientId value comes at other line of code but not here.
when i use in the below code this.clientId works. but no in the above code that i shared

```
this.patientReportForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       patientId : new FormControl(Number(this.clientId)),
      hubxCategoryId: ['',Validators.required],
```

this is my model.Here clientId holds the patientId value.

```
export class HubxModel{ 
    id: number;
    categoryId: number;
    itemTitle: string;
    itemUnit: string;
    isActive: boolean=true;
    itemValue: string;
    patientId: number;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}
```

here clientId value has received but when i submit patientid is null
[image: clientid]

Comment: You’d really want to show the entire component, especially with errors like this.

Comment: please check entire component is too large to share but i showed some part

Comment: It’s not much clearer, however, the error is quite descriptive. Try this clientId: number | undefined = undefined;

Comment: thanks error is gone but when i submit patientId didnt carry the clientId value.but when i debug and check this.clientid shows the clientId value. what might be the issue

Comment: Your subscribe is async, you probably need to move the logic to setup your form inside the subscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this because the **strict** is enabled in `tscconfig.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
```

so you will force to set an initial value to class property

```
clientId: number = 0;
```

you can read more about this here [strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)  and this rule [strictPropertyInitialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization)

Comment: thanks it works. But i have one question in the above code patientid: this.clientid has a value when i check by debugging but when i submit patientId is null what might be the issue

Comment: you can share a full component code at **stackblitz** I will be happy to check it for you

Answer (score 0):

As error says, you are using the value of `clientId` before its  initialisation, so try doing all the things after you set the value of `this.clientId` in queryParams subscribe.

can help more accurately if you share your component.ts file.